# Can't get PHP environment variables to work locally - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, apache2, ubuntu-16.04, slim

After doing a thorough review of all the documentation, StackOverflow questions, and blog posts I can on this specific thing... together with a couple hours of troubleshooting, I still cannot find out how to get basic environment variables usage to work in my Slim PHP project.

This is my first PHP web application project and certainly my first time getting environment variables to work in PHP.

Basically what I'm trying to do is set a password as environment variable in a local `.htaccess` file so that password isn't exposed insecurely in the code I'm pushing to GitHub (***.htaccess is set to be ignored on my project by git***).

I'd basically like to have the following code work:

`.htaccess` file:

```
SetEnv PASSWORD superSecretPassw0rd
```

And later on in the appropriate place(s) in my project's PHP files retrieve that variable and use it in sending emails via SMTP.

For example in `/app/routes.php`:

```
$mail->Password = getenv("PASSWORD");
```

Right now, I am doing the first part, setting the environment variable in the `.htaccess` file. In fact, I've tried setting the Environment Variable in each of the following ways:

```
SetEnv HTTP_PASSWORD NeTzj6gKJp5q

SetEnv PASSWORD glop

RewriteRule .* - [E=TEST:PasswordJOKES10]
```

Yet when I `var_dump(getenv("TEST"));` the variable shows up as `bool(false)`.

It's possible my `.htaccess` file isn't being read at all. When I delete the contents of the `.htaccess` file everything basically runs the same, which it also does if the file is just filled with long random lines of text.

I've also made sure that `module rewrite is enabled`. So that's not the issue.

I've also checked over the settings for `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`. The most important settings look like I have them set right:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
AccessFileName .htaccess
```

`AllowOverride All` is set which supposedly makes it so `.htaccess` files can work, and the `AccessFileName` is set to `.htaccess`.

The full path of my project is `/var/www/html/east-end-php-site/` with directory structure basically like this:

```
/east-end-php-site/
  |-----> /app/
  |-----> /config/
  |-----> /vendor/
 composer.json
 README.md
 .htaccess
 index.php
```

My local setup:

- Ubuntu -v 16.04
- Apache2 -v 2.4.18
- PHP -v 7.0.22

Project is run by running command `php -S localhost:8000` in the terminal from the root of that directory.

I've currently hit a wall on this one. Please tell me StackOverflow comrades, what am I doing wrong? Where should I take my troubleshooting next? What might fix this?

**Extra Reference 1**

The whole `.htaccess` file looks like this:

```
AllowOverride ALL

RewriteEngine On

SetEnv HTTP_TEST NeTzj6gKJp5q

SetEnv TEST glop


# Some hosts may require you to use the `RewriteBase` directive.
# If you need to use the `RewriteBase` directive, it should be the
# absolute physical path to the directory that contains this htaccess file.

RewriteBase /var/www/html/east-end-php-site/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule .* - [E=TEST:PasswordJOKES10]
```

Comment: What's the full path of your `.htaccess` file? You mention that if you put random strings in it, nothing happens. That should definitely throw an error, which might mean that the file is not being read. Try having a look at the logs anyway at `/var/log/apache2/error.log` and pasting the file inside your <Directory> tag in `apache2.conf` (remember to reload the server afterwards).

Comment: Ok I'm gonna add the full path of my .htaccess file in the question. Real quick - its `/var/www/html/east-end-php-site/.htaccess`. Let me go look at the logs. I'll also go paste the file in that tag. Great suggestions!

Comment: I added everything from .htaccess in that `<Directory>` tag, didn't work. Then I tried adding a `<Directory /var/www/html/east-end-php-site>` tag with everything from `.htaccess`. That didn't work either.

Comment: Got this from the `/var/log/apache2/error.log`: `[Tue Sep 19 19:03:31.632280 2017] [core:alert] [pid 4299] [client ::1:49656] /var/www/.htaccess: RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters
[Tue Sep 19 19:03:31.836227 2017] [core:alert] [pid 4300] [client ::1:49658] /var/www/.htaccess: RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters, referer: http://localhost/`

Comment: HTAccess files do not apply when you are testing via the builtin server

Comment: Woah ok I don't know what that means but it sounds promising, as in it seems you know what the problem is.

Comment: @geggleto do you know how to change that behavior? I.e. "fix it". How can I get the .htaccess file to apply? How do I move off of the "builtin server". If your answer fixes my question I'd gladly accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. .htaccess ONLY applies to apache and will not work with the built-in web server
2. To mock $_ENV variables you should use https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv